# angularjs controller fucntion does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The idea is to create a function that triggers a pop up when clicking on the word.

This is what I have done so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="contenu" >
        <div class="box1">
          <a href="#" ng-model="collapsedd" ng-click="toggle()"  style="color:#259B24"> MyRhoom </a>
          <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsedd">I am description</div>
        </div>
```

**Js controller**

```
angular.module('starter.toolsController', ['ionic'])
.controller('toolsCtrl', function ($scope){

$scope.collapsedd="false";
$scope.toggle=function()
{
    $scope.collapsedd=!$scope.collapsedd;
};

});
```

But I get this:

[image: picture]

Meaning that the pop up is fired already!
How to fix this?

Comment: `ng-model` does not make sense in `<a>`

Comment: What to use instead?

Comment: nothing, just remove it from `<a>`

Comment: and how to define "collapsedd"?

Comment: @Hana you have already defined it in the controller by `$scope.collapsedd = false;`.

Comment: like this?:  <a href="#"  ng-click="toggle()" tyle="color:#259B24"> MyRhoom </a>
              <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsedd">I am description</div>

Comment: @Hana yes just remove it as is done in my answer.

Comment: yeah but it still does not work. The links disappeared totally.

Comment: @Hana, can you provide working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/PPtyT7

Comment: @Hana, seems your code work: https://plnkr.co/edit/wa9OpQFFIcfg0o2aCeTu?p=preview

Comment: @Hana, just add needed reference, and add `ng-app`

Comment: what reference? ng-app is in another page...

Comment: @Hana, what you mean _ng-app is in another page_? all angular directives should be inside element with this attribute

Comment: I Have some many pages in my application and this is one of it. THe ng-app is in the index.html and this is tools.html and it has a controller called toolsCtrl

Comment: @Hana, so, you use angular wrong :-)

Comment: If you use ionic, I suggest that you should debug the code in chrome. Have a look at your console to see if there are some errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no big problem with your code. I've just replaced `$scope.collapsedd = 'false'` with `$scope.collapsedd = false` and it has been working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="contenu" ng-controller="toolsCtrl">
  <div class="box1">
    <a href="#" ng-click="toggle()" style="color:#259B24"> MyRhoom </a>
    <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsedd">I am description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('toolsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.collapsedd = false;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.collapsedd = !$scope.collapsedd;
  };
});
```

Comment: Now the whole word (link) is gone :/ I don't know why. It works just fine on the browser and emulator.

Comment: @Hana well, you should always avoid "false" (string) as boolean in your case. This could lead to some unexpected behaviors in earlier versions of angularjs.